# mpdf How to set Output file every one page

Tags: php, mpdf

Sorry about my grammar .

"I tried to export multiple pages more than 1000 page because it's make the server is time out. very sorry about my grammar."

in php i set loop write html to file by mPdf 
But it's has alot of pages is more than 1000 pages and it's make the server time out.

Can i  set Output file every one page  or any idea ?

Now I have one idea to get output HTML then send its to database and then select and refresh per one page and merge pdf again .But it's dont have a page number in output HTML from mpdf or anything to know about each page.

Please Help my . If you have more idea.

This is Example from my code

```html
      

       
        
        $this->mpdf = new mPDF('th', 'A4', '0'); // mode - default ''
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html); // สั่งให้ mPDF เขียนไฟล์ pdf
        $this->mpdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;

        ####
        $file_name = 'report1_' . $lot . '_' . $id;
        ob_start();
        $arr_data = array();
        $arr_data_tmp = array();
        ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/css/style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <?php

        $data= array(.....); //a lot data From DB;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                  //The detail is alot data 
        } 

        ?>
     

        <?php
       
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        
      
        $filename_set = $file_name . '.pdf';
        $this->mpdf->Output('file_upload/report1/' . $lot . '/' . $filename_set, 'F');

            
        die();
```

Comment: what have you tried? where did you run into problems? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to export multiple pages more than 1000 page because it's make the server is time out.

very sorry about my grammar .

Comment: it's not about grammar. show some *code*. something you have tried. do not expect people to solve your problem from scratch. this way you will probably get no answers.